# Read the file contents from all the files present in a specified folder

Tags: c#, file

I have to read the file contents from all the files present in a specific folder. Can you guys help me out regarding this?

```
 DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Test");
 FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*"); 
 string str = "";
 foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
  **//Do something here to get the file contents..!**
}
```

PS:**ReadAllText** is not working!! and **StreamReader** is giving error:

> An object reference is required for non static field, method or property.

Comment: What file format are these files ? and what is the content ?

Comment: "is not working" is a _really_ bad error description, no matter how many exclamation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.IO;
...
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.*"))
{
    string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
}
```

The above is a .NET 4.0 feature; in previous versions, you'll need to replace EnumerateFiles with GetFiles.

Comment: What about non-text files?